# Media query not working with jquery

Tags: jquery

As you can see in my pen, every time I click on retail or wholesale, I prevent the redirection and instead it opens a tab.

How can I allow my code to work from devices that are bigger than 767 or whatever size I want?

At the moment my jQuery looks like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 767 ){
            $('#retail a').on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('li.retail').toggleClass('display');
                $(this).toggleClass('angle');
            });

            $('#wholesale a').on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('li.wholesale').toggleClass('display');
                $(this).toggleClass('angle');
            }); 
     }  
});
```

You can also check my [full code here](https://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/VzVGPQ)

Comment: you codepen is working fine

Comment: @AlivetoDie they are not having toggle effect. Either of them should be displayed.

Comment: My code works regardless of the window width so it is wrong. Cause if am on screen that is less than 767 and click on retail, it does not redirect

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#retail a').on("click", function(e){
            if($(window).width() > 767 ){
            $('li.retail').toggleClass('display');
            $(this).toggleClass('angle');
           }
        });
        $('#wholesale a').on("click", function(e){
            if($(window).width() > 767 ){
            $('li.wholesale').toggleClass('display');
            $(this).toggleClass('angle');
           }
        }); 
 } });
```

Please add if condition within click event. See my above code.

Comment: The idea is correct and appreciate the support.  I just re-added the prevent defaults and removed and extra brace.
Happy coding

Comment: if a tag has # then it will be the necessary event.preventDefault()

Comment: Just a quick one....I noticed that the code only works when I start resizing the page. Is there a way to trigger  the resize by default?

Comment: If you add your code in $(window).resize, please remove it. We have added code to  $(document).ready so it should be work

Comment: Resize works and you can check my final answer. Appreciate the support thiough

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `$(window).resize()` function. I'ved tried this before and it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 767 ){
            $('#retail a').on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('li.retail').toggleClass('display');
                $(this).toggleClass('angle');
            });

            $('#wholesale a').on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('li.wholesale').toggleClass('display');
                $(this).toggleClass('angle');
            }); 
     }  
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function(){ 
       // your code

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work successfully, I used the resize function and triggered the resize so that the browser can detect the window width without having to start resizing and the jquery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() > 767 ){
            $('#retail a').on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('li.retail').toggleClass('display');
                $(this).toggleClass('angle');
            });

            $('#wholesale a').on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('li.wholesale').toggleClass('display');
                $(this).toggleClass('angle');
            }); 
         }  
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```